# C program execution success apparently depends on file name

Tags: c

I tried to run a C source file and the result was it got stuck in an infinite loop. I literally copied and pasted the same code into a new source file, Untitled1, and it ran fine. Both the original and the new source file are saved on the desktop. Why is this happening?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i, j, d, a;
    scanf("%d %d", &i, &d);

    printf("%d\n", i);

    a = 1;
    while(i>1)
    {
        i = i%d;

        for(j = 1; j<=a; j++)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }

        printf("%d\n", i);

        d = d/100;

        a++;
    }
    //////////
    return 0;
}
```

Just a simple exercise from CodesDope. The goal is to print

```
1010101
 10101
  101
   1
```

Which you get by entering i=1010101 and d=1000000.

Comment: What's the problem ?

Comment: Says right in the first paragraph. I guess I just have a corrupted file?

Comment: Above mentioned code is running under one file name but not under another.

Comment: Remove space in scanf. Scanf don't have space in them. Try may be it work.

Comment: @pmac there is nothing like corrupt file. It must be some code issue.

Comment: @problematicDude You are wrong; spaces are allowed and have well-defined behavior in `scanf`.

Comment: OT: the posted code outputs the desired pattern.  However, I would strongly suggest always checking the returned value from any of the `scanf()` family of functions.  Those functions return the number of successful 'input format conversion' specifications.  (in the OPs posted code any returned value other than 2 indicates an error occurred

Comment: @JosephSible But I just did the same thing again! I tried running the original code: didn't work. Copied-pasted that exact code into a new file: worked. But I just figured something else out. When I enter different numbers for the new code, it runs as should. When I enter different numbers in the original code it is printing a christmas tree of *'s, which is from a completely different code I was working on before that. So basically when I compile and run the 'corrupt' code, it is running another programs code! So it is trying to print a christmas tree of 1010101 lines. Very weird.

Comment: even happens after restarting

Comment: copy the file to another folder and try again. Did you use the same name to compile a different code before? are you accessing the correct files to compile?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot doubt your experience but I'm not sure your conclusion is correct.  First we don't run source code, it has to be compiled first.  This leaves open the possibility that you have an old executable, i.e. an executable that doesn't reflect the code.  The same code compiled the same way should produce the same runtime behavior (given that that code logic is correct).

Since all the variables are integer the `d` variable can become 0 and if this happens before `i` becomes less than or equal to 1 the `i%d` would result in a divide by zero error.  Trying your code on repl.it with i = 1000 and d = 77 generates a floating point exception, but different compilers/environments may surface that undefined state differently (though all should produce an error state).

My advice is to delete both your compiled executables and any object files (clean your project), then recompile and compare results.  If you still see different behavior based on the same output, then carefully compare your source files (or 'diff' them if you are on a unix'y system).  If you still find a discrepancy, update your question with both source files (even if you find them identical), the compiler (name/version) and environment (OS/version) you are using.